# drawing smooth path through symmetric points, gives non symmetric curve

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, coordinates

I want to make a graphic going through some points. I've choose the points symmetric, to have a symmetric curve, but the curve is not. I could define some extra points, but their must be a better option?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymin=0,ymax=9,xmin=0,xmax=14]
\tkzClip
\tkzGrid
\tkzDefPoints{1/2/A, 1/8/Y, 13/2/X, 1/7/B, 13/7/E, 7/3/K, 7/7/L, 4/3.5/J, 10/3.5/M}
\tkzLabelPoints[above right](B,E);
 \draw[->, very thick] (A) -- (Y) node[above, yshift=-1cm, xshift=-0.3cm, rotate=90] {effectiviteit};
 \draw[->, very thick] (A) -- (X) node[below, xshift=-0.4cm, yshift=-0.3cm] {tijd};
 \tkzDrawPoints[color=red, fill=red](B,E);
 %\draw[thick,blue,rounded corners=15mm] (B)--(K)--(E);
 \draw[very thick, red] plot [smooth] coordinates {(B) (J) (L) (M) (E)};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}
 \end{document}
```

Resulting in

[image]

The next picture (based on this one) should be:

[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: sorry, I was to quick, I will do

Comment: What's not symmetric? Or where is the symmetry meant to be?

Comment: The first half of the curve B-J-L. If you look carefully then the red line is closer to the (3,4) than to the (5,4). It also goes through (6,6) but not through (2,6). You have the same problem with the secund half of the curve.

Comment: Isn't that because the angle leaving B and the angle entering E are not going to be the same as those entering and leaving L? That is, those for L are affected by what is happening to the curve next or where the curve came from, whereas those at B and E are not.

Comment: I see. I haven't looked at it this way, but that could indeed be the problem. So I will have to look another way to do this. :-(

Comment: I've posted one way to make it symmetric by plotting a longer curve but clipping it at the desired start/end points. However, I don't know if this solution will actually work for your situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make the graph symmetric by ensuring that the angles at which the curve leaves B and enters E match those at L. One way to do this is to plot the curve before B and after E but clip what is drawn so that only that between B and E is displayed.

```
\documentclass[tikz,10pt,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \tkzInit[ymin=0,ymax=9,xmin=0,xmax=14]
      \tkzClip
      \tkzGrid
      \tkzDefPoints{1/2/A, 1/8/Y, 13/2/X, 1/7/B, 13/7/E, 7/3/K, 7/7/L, 4/3.5/J, 10/3.5/M, -2/3.5/C, 16/3.5/D}
      \tkzLabelPoints[above right](B,E);
      \draw[->, very thick] (A) -- (Y) node[above, yshift=-1cm, xshift=-0.3cm, rotate=90] {effectiviteit};
      \draw[->, very thick] (A) -- (X) node[below, xshift=-0.4cm, yshift=-0.3cm] {tijd};
      \tkzDrawPoints[color=red, fill=red](B,E);
      %\draw[thick,blue,rounded corners=15mm] (B)--(K)--(E);
      \begin{scope}
        \clip (B |- Y) -| (E |- X) -| cycle;
        \draw[very thick, red] plot [smooth] coordinates {(C) (B) (J) (L) (M) (E) (D)};
      \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: symmetric curve]

Some explanation of

```
\clip (B |- Y) -| (E |- X) -| cycle;
```

`(B |- Y)` defines a coordinate which is vertically aligned with B and horizontally aligned with Y. (It needs to go above B else the very top of the curve at L gets flattened off.) Similarly `(E |- X)` is the coordinate vertically aligned with E and horizontally aligned with X. In other words, it uses E's *x* coordinate and X's *y* coordinate.

`(p) -| (q)` tells TiKZ to construct a path from p to q which does all of the horizontal stuff first and then all of the vertical stuff.

So `(B |- Y) -| (E |- X) -| cycle` defines a rectangular path from a coordinate a bit above B across to a coordinate a bit above E and then down to a coordinate far below E and then across to a coordinate far below B and then back up to the coordinate a bit above B.

That rectangle defines the region to which the drawing of the plot is clipped. Anything outside that rectangular region is simply not displayed.

Here's a diagram which may be a bit clearer:

[image: construction of clipping]

Comment: It couldn't be better! If only I could understand \clip (B |- Y) -| (E |- X) -| cycle; Although you explained it in your answer, I don't understand the |- and the |-

Comment: @Arne I've added some explanation of what is going on and a diagram which may be a bit clearer than my attempt at explanation!

Answer (score 9):

Try the Hobby Tikz library.  It allows you to specify the incoming and outgoing angles, and produces a smoother curve.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymin=0,ymax=9,xmin=0,xmax=14]
\tkzClip

\tkzGrid
\tkzDefPoints{1/2/A, 1/8/Y, 13/2/X, 1/7/B, 13/7/E, 7/3/K, 7/7/L, 4/3.5/J, 10/3.5/M}
\tkzLabelPoints[above right](B,E);
 \draw[->, very thick] (A) -- (Y) node[above, yshift=-1cm, xshift=-0.3cm, rotate=90] {effectiviteit};
 \draw[->, very thick] (A) -- (X) node[below, xshift=-0.4cm, yshift=-0.3cm] {tijd};
 \tkzDrawPoints[color=red, fill=red](B,E);
 %\draw[thick,blue,rounded corners=15mm] (B)--(K)--(E);

 \draw[very thick, red] plot [smooth] coordinates {(B) (J) (L) (M) (E)};
\draw[use Hobby shortcut,blue] ([out angle=0,in angle=180]B) .. (J) .. (L) .. (M) .. (E);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}
 \end{document}
```

<strike>(Unfortunately, I'm on my iPad at the moment so can't upload a screenshot.  I can assure you that it looks beautiful and symmetric.)</strike>

[image]